# Send and retrieve two dynamic length values to safeTransferFrom data argument

Tags: solidity

I'm sending two dynamic length values to the `data` argument in the `safeTransferFrom` function via OpenZeppelin ERC721.

See here:

[image]

Now, I want to create a function that decodes the two values and assigns them to a their own separate public variables.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Converting them to hex might work but I'm having a bit of trouble extracting the values.